# Python noob for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following variable called `request.FILES` which contain the following:

```
<MultiValueDict: {
    u'uploadedFile': [
        <InMemoryUploadedFile: angularjs1.png (image/png)>,
        <InMemoryUploadedFile: angularjs2.png (image/png)>,
        <InMemoryUploadedFile: angularjs3.png (image/png)>]}>
```

If I call or print `request.FILES['uploadedFile']` I get only `angularjs3.png` and I need a list like `angularjs1.png, angularjs2.png, angularjs3.png` or something similar. I think I need a for loop but I didn't succeed how to make it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a special type of dictionary, a `MultiValueDict`. Using the `.get()` method or `[...]` indexing will only ever get you the *first* value.

You need to use the [`.getlist()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) instead:

```
request.FILES.getlist('uploadedFile')
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `.getall()` method is not working because `MultiValueDict` object has no atribute `getall`

Comment: @MariusNV: Sorry, you didn't specify the framework. It's Django instead, right?

Comment: Yes, it's Django and I didn't know that it has his specific way of handling this.

Comment: @martin-pieters Thank you for the documentation link :D